# Upload zip files directly to AWS S3 bucket from website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, upload, bigdata

Is it possible to directly upload data files from a website to an AWS S3 bucket without having to first download the files to my PC? These are large files (60 GB) and will tie up my PC for a week downloading, prepping, and then uploading the tables to my S3 bucket.

I see in my S3 Management Console there are options to "Add files" and "Add folder" but I don't see a place where I can enter the original URL location of the data files.

The data files are located [here](https://acic2022.mathematica.org/data) (scroll to bottom of page); URLs for the data are:

https://acic2022.mathematica.org/data/track1a_20220404.zip

https://acic2022.mathematica.org/data/track1b_20220404.zip

https://acic2022.mathematica.org/data/track1c_20220404.zip

Thanks!

Comment: S3 offers no such API.  You'll need to explore other options, like spinning up a EC2 instance with enough storage to download to the EC2 instance and send to S3, or using something like s3fs on an EC2 instance to transfer from the website to S3.

Comment: @AnonCoward Thank you - that sounds like a simpler solution. Do you know how to set up a connection in my EC2 instance with the data file URLs?

Comment: Plenty of options depending on the exact situation, one such is to launch an instance, and use wget to download the file, then aws's cli to transfer to s3.

Answer (score 1):

So, the below script worked well for small files, in other words, you have to wait until the download ends the process before it initializes the upload to bucket s3, which might take a long while. During that time you'll only see the bucket created.

The bucket will be created for the default zone: us-east-1. A programmatic user is mandatory with admin permissions, once you will need to deal with AWS CLI through an automated process.

You'll only need to change the variable **FILE** that has to be the last node of your source path.

```
FILE="track1a_20220404.zip"
BCKT="math-files-s3"
SRC="https://acic2022.mathematica.org/data/$FILE"
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket $BCKT | \
wget -O- $SRC | aws s3 cp - s3://$BCKT/$FILE
```

Just editing to provide screenshots as proof of work...
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In addition, for your real scenario --to become your on-premise environment a "serverless" on this task, this link should help you..
https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/amazon-s3-as-a-file-system